# how to use bitmap as source for image in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

In my application i want to drawing a rectangle on image box using bitmap called myBitmap. and the problem is how to use System.Drawing.bitMap as source for image in C# Wpf .

```
   private void MyRectangle(System.Drawing.Point p1, System.Drawing.Point p2)
    {
        int var1,var2;
        var1 = Convert.ToInt16(image1.Width);
        var2 = Convert.ToInt16(image1.Height);

        System.Drawing.Bitmap myBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(var1,var2);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.LightBlue);
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Red),p1.X, p1.Y, p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y);
        }


      // this.image1.Source = myBitmap;

    }
```

Comment: you may perhaps use shape classes or event geometry in this scenario unless bitmap is the a extreme necessity.

Comment: Do not use WinForms bitmaps in a WPF application. Use [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to BitmapSource, use the BitmapSource as the Source of your Image control.

```
    public static BitmapSource ConvertToBitmapSource(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if (bitmap == null)
            return null;
        //BitmapImage b=new BitmapImage();
        BitmapSource bitSrc = null;
        var hBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;


        try
        {
            hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
            bitSrc = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                hBitmap,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        catch (Win32Exception)
        {
            bitSrc = null;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            if (hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
                DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            hBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
                DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            bitSrc = null;
            hBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        finally
        {
            //bitmap.Dispose();
            if (hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
                DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        }
        return bitSrc;
    }


    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```

Comment: another method you can use     public static BitmapImage ConvertToBitmapImage(Image bitmap)
        {
            if (bitmap == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bitmap");
            BitmapImage im = new BitmapImage();
            try
            {
                im.BeginInit();
                im.StreamSource = new MemoryStream();
                bitmap.Save(im.StreamSource, ImageFormat.Png);
                im.EndInit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return im;
        }

Comment: And simply you can convert Bitmap to byte[] and bind to the byte[] directly